# Is the Software Construction Toolkit (from Google) any good?

Tags: build-automation

Is anyone using the [Software Construction Toolkit](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2009/02/software-construction-toolkit-released.html) from Google? Is it good enough to replace `make` and/or `ant`? How good is it with its many advertised platforms (java, .net, C++)?

What are your opinions on it?

Actually this is Google´s modification on top of the [Scons](http://www.scons.org/).

EDIT: No answers yet! So, nobody is using? I'll post my impressions soon.

Answer (score 3):

I used Scons for some time and found it had several problems. Therefore I switched back to Autotools, which is a PITA itself.

Currently I recommend Waf: http://code.google.com/p/waf/

That's all I can say, I didn't use the Google thing myself. But if you compare to "make" alone (not Autotools), Scons alone is superiour.

Answer (score 2):

I have an impression that it is inbreed toolkit maintained only for Google projects (chrome?). (just like dmake for Open Office).